# Hide/Fix Macbook Pro Retina Screen Scratch

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, repair

I noticed that I have a small scratch on my Macbook Pro Retina's screen.  When this has happened on my desktop LCDs I've used some Vaseline to hide it.  While I know that doesn't actually fix it I am looking for a technique to make this scratch less noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Possible [methods](http://www.877geeksonsite.com/computer-repair-blog/laptop-repair/mind-the-gap-how-to-fill-scratches-in-computer-screens/) depending on the scratch depth.

1- Fill it - for deep scratches.

Fill it with toothpaste! or professional glass filler.

> Believe it or not, toothpaste can be used to patch some screen
>   scratches. Actual toothpaste, not gel or paste-mouthwash hybrids, must
>   be used. Users should gently massage the paste into the scratch with
>   their fingers using a circular motion. If done properly, the paste
>   should adhere to the scratch and polish it away. Then, use a soft
>   cloth to remove excess paste from the screen. Finally, use glass
>   cleaner or a special screen cleaner to remove any additional residue.
>
> Petroleum jelly can also be applied in a similar manner, although it
>   may need to be reapplied if a user happens to rub his or her screen
>   and removes it from the scratch. While toothpaste is an abrasive that
>   pares down a scratch, petroleum jelly fills the scratch because it
>   closely matches the optical density of the LCD display.

2- Polish- for shallow scratches

Get the glass polish in any computer or similar store.

Pro..works well on shallow scratches

Con.. you will create a larger portion on your screen with lower transparency due to polishing.